# gnuplot: keep tics, remove labels

Tags: gnuplot

The x axis on my gnuplot looks similar to this:

2 4 8 16 32 64 72 86 98 112 128 256 512 1024 ... 1048576

So these are log2 values that go from 2, 4, 8 .. 1048576. The problem is that there are certain intermediate values like 72,86,98,112 etc. which are not log2 based values, and are so close to each other that the labels overlap. Is there a way I can keep the tics (i.e. plot the values) but not display the labels on the x axis? 
I want to display only those labels that are an exact power of 2, but I want to show all values on the plot.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean x-values are power of two? I generate a fake dataset using those 20 x's and random y but the x-axis doesn't show up as described in your post. Could you provide a short overview of your dataset. Also, [Gnuplot not so Frequently Asked Questions](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/tics-e.html) might prove helpful in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just define the xtics manually... for example:

```
set xtics ("2" 2,"4" 4, "8" 8,"16" 16,"32" 32,"64" 64)
```