# gnuplot, hide default xtics, add xtics

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to remove the xtics from a plot (text labels and small vertical lines) and replace with my own customized xtics (labels vertical lines). I could add text labels and arrows without heads instead of xtics (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/textrotate.html), but there has to be a simpler solution.

I tried this:

```
unset xtics
set xtics format ""
set xtics scale 0
set xtics add ("someTicLabel1" someFloat1)
set xtics add ("someTicLabel2" someFloat2)
```

It gets rid of the default xtics labels, but the xtic vertical lines remain. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, this is the wrong question! This _does not_ remove the tics. It removes their labels. The tics are still visible. Since I want to know how to actually remove the tics, this formation of the question is a problem...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read a solution to a similar problem ([gnuplot: keep tics, remove labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946904/gnuplot-keep-tics-remove-labels)) and I realized the solution to my problem is not to use set xtics add, but set xtics:

```
unset xtics
set xtics format " "
set xtics ("someTicLabel1" someFloat1, "someTicLabel2" someFloat2)
```

Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't need the `set xtics format " "` when I did this.

Comment: @Max Which version? Perhaps they changed things?

Comment: @tommy.carstensen  maybe you want to accept your own solution, then this question doesn't appear as unanswered anymore.

Comment: @theozh Thanks for making me aware! Accepted.

Comment: This only removes the labels of tics.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone really needs to remove the ticks and not just their labels...

```
unset ytics
set ytics format '' scale 0
```

`unset ytics` (`xtics` etc) just restores the default ticks.

`set ytics format ''` (`xtics` etc) just removes the labels of default ticks.

`set ytics scale 0` (`xtics` etc) makes default ticks' size 0.

Btw, this still does not remove the default ticks ' gridlines, if you do `set grid ytics back lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "grey"` (`xtics` etc) you will see them. Of course, there is `set grid noytics` (`noxtics` etc).

In other words, I have not found a way to remove the ticks, but only to make them invisible...